# Objective C iPhone: Open PDF doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, appdelegate

So far I could open a PDF from anywhere on my iPhone and choose "Export to..." my app and then it started an import mechanism in my app.

I've implemented the Facebook SDK now and I assume it has to do with implementing this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

So far I haven't implemented this method. And now I pasted this code into the app delegate. When I choose a PDF and select my app it opens my app, but nothing happens. I assume it has something to do with this? What do I need to change to being able again to open PDFs?

And what I also had to add was this in the info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
```

Of course I already had some CFBundleURLTypes. And I just added the string within the array. Is this maybe the error?

Comment: What’s the “import mechanism” you mentioned? How was it called before?

Comment: Well when you open a PDF and choose „Open in“ and then my app. The normal function of iOS how to open documents in certain apps. That used to work until I impemented Facebook

Comment: I mean, what did your app do with the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the PDF where you see the comment `// Add any custom logic here.`. You must have deleted the old logic when you added this FB code. Check your old commit for the old logic and put it there.

Answer (score -1):

There can be possibility something is overwritten while adding FB key in info.plist